# Xcode8: File Structure Quick View Seperator ('//MARK: -')

Tags: xcode8

I love the way how `//MARK: -` helps to separate the definitions in File Structure Quick View. However in Xcode8 such comment pattern has a usual Mark behaviour (bold text only).

**Do you guys know its Xcode8 counterpart?**

Reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Now `MARK` needs to have no text after a colon. So both empty `//MARK:`, `//TODO:` will produce a line separator inside the quick view.

Comment: It's not only in Xcode 8 it also there in xcode 7.x if you write //MARK: it will produce a  seperate line.